# small window "Launching application" when I open .application winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an experimental winform which is tiny:

- 20 lines of added code
- two controls
- datagridview
- a small Sql Server Compact db included - with a table containing 3 rows of data

When I launch the .application file a small window appears saying "Launching Application" and then disappears after half a second whilst the form becomes visible.

Is this usual and should I expect this message with every winform I create?

Comment: No, a window that says "Lauching application" is entirely non-standard.  Could be a custom splash screen but you'd know about that.  Whatever is going on, it won't happen on your user's machine.

Comment: ok - I'll test on a friends pc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're invoking a ClickOnce deployment file. If you invoke the .exe directly you should not see the 'Launching...' message.

Comment: this is highlighting my lack of knowledge of the difference between deploy/publish/build etc ! I published and then ran the install file and then assumed that the .application file was the final result - am I doing something wrong?